# Is my proof for boundedness correct?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

I was given this question:

Let $h \in L^{1}([0,1], m)$ and let $F$ be a linear functional on the normed space $C[0,1]$ (with the maximum norm), defined by $F(g) = \int_{0}^{1} hg.$ Prove that $F$ is a bounded linear functional on $C[0,1]$ and determine its norm.

**My trial:**

Since $|F(g)| = |\int_{0}^{1} h(t)g(t) dt| \leq \int_{0}^{1}|h(t)||g(t)| \leq \max_{t\in [0,1]} |g(t)|.\int_{0}^{1}  |h(t)|(1-0) = \||g\|_{max} \|h\|.$

Therefore, $\|F\| \leq \|h\|.$

Comment: So the norm I used for the function $h$ is correct @MaximilianJanisch?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch That's not true: There is no assumption on $h$ being positive (of course... the operator norm and the $L^1$ *do* coincide, the $1$ function just doesn't necessarily show it).

Comment: Is my proof correct?@WoolierThanThou so what is your suggestion for the euality of the norm

Comment: @Mathstupid Yes, the proof is correct

Comment: and how these functions  will behave could you show me the details?, how they will give me the equality @MaximilianJanisch

Comment: I'm typing up an answer. Give me a few.

Comment: And how is the use of the symbol $m$ "the measure" will be used ?@MaximilianJanisch

Comment: I can not see the set $S$@MaximilianJanisch

Comment: what about my previous question?@MaximilianJanisch

Comment: @Mathstupid You are integrating $h$ with respect to $m$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch so in my first equality ... the correct way to write it is how?

Comment: @Mathstupid You can write $\int \,\mathrm dm(t)$ or $\int\, m(\mathrm dt)$ and so it doesn't matter too much

Comment: do you mean that the measure depends on $t$? @MaximilianJanisch

Comment: @Mathstupid No it is just a way of writing the integral with respect to the measure $m$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything you've done so far is correct. To finish, assume first $0=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=1$ such that $h=\sum_{k=1}^n c_k1_{[x_{k-1},x_k)}$ for some constants $c_k$. Let $g_n$ be some continuous function such that $g_n\equiv \frac{c_k}{|c_k|}$ on $[\frac{n+1}{n}x_{k-1}, \frac{n-1}{n}x_k]$ for every $k$ such that $c_k\neq 0$ and $0$ otherwise. Furthermore, we impose that $|g_n|\leq 1$. Such a function can be constructed as piecewise affine.

Then, $\|g_n\|_{\infty}=1$ for all $n$ and $\int h g_n\textrm{d}m\to \int |h|\textrm{d}m$ implying the desired in *this* case.9

Now, functions of this form are dense in $L^1([0,1],m)$, since the half-open intervals generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the measure is finite and the constant $1$ function is almost everywhere equal to $1_{[0,1)}$. Note, furthermore, that if $h_n\xrightarrow{L^1} h$, we have, for all continuous $f$ that

$$
\left| \int h_nf \textrm{d}m-\int h f\textrm{d}m\right|\leq \|h_n-h\|_{L^1} \|f\|_{\infty}
$$
This implies that the map  $\varphi(h)= F_h$ is a continuous map from $L^1$ to $C([0,1])^*$. Since $\varphi$ is an isometry on the dense set of simple functions of the above form, then $\varphi$ is an isometry. This concludes the proof.

Comment: but I think in my proof it should be dm not dt .... correct?

Comment: I don't really care whether you write one or the other. :P The literature calls the Lesbegue measure $m$, $\lambda$ and $\textrm{d}x$ with more or less equal frequency.

Comment: Nice, I just noticed that OP still has to show linearity but that is very easy

Comment: I meant to have a continuous function in the integrand ... is that correct? is my $h$ also continuous?

Comment: @Mathstupid $h$ does not have to be continuous, only integrable

Comment: Note, though, that there is a lemma needed here: Let $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ and $\mu$ a finite measure on $\mathcal{F}$. Then, $\textrm{span}_{\mathbb{R}} \{ 1_A|\;A\in\mathcal{A}\}$ is dense in $L^1(\mu)$ if and only if the constant $1$ function lies in the closure.

Comment: Alternatively, you can test against continuous functions, since they also change signs on intervals. The proof is more or less the same but it *does* avoid having to prove the above lemma. You have to know that the continuous functions are dense in $L^1$ though, and I guess the usual proof of that is that they can approximate indicators on intervals, so maybe that's circular.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou If you prove that continuous functions can $L^1$-approximate all indicator functions arbitrarily well then you can also succeed directly with approximations $f_n\in\mathcal C([0,1])$ that are absolutely bounded by $1$ and approximate the sign function of $h$

Comment: Sure... I'm saying that I think the only good way of doing that is approximating indicators on intervals, and then you need to know the span of the indicators on intervals are dense, and then you need the above lemma.

Comment: so the norm is $\|h\|_{1}$?

Comment: Exactly. The natural map from $L^1([0,1])$ into the dual of $C([0,1])$ (or $L^{\infty}([0,1])$ ofr the matter) is an isometry!

Comment: Are $g_{n}$ continuous?how?

Comment: How do you know this"since the half-open intervals generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra "?

Comment: It's pretty easy to see that the $g_n$ can be chosen continuous. Try drawing the situation if that helps. Are you asking why the half-open intervals generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: yes I am asking this

Comment: why u first was in need of $g_{n}$ and then of $h_{n}$? I do not understand the logical sequence in your solution.

Comment: Could you please give me a proof for that $g_{n}$ are continuous?

Comment: Is your main idea in the solution is proving that the subspace of simple functions in $L^p$ is dense in $L^p$?

Comment: First, you check the functional when *h* is nice - i.e. a certain kind of simple function. This can be done by checking its action on certain sequences. Then, you want to extend to argument to general $h$, which can be done via sequences. As for why the $g_n$ can be chosen continuous, I suggest you do what I suggested and draw the situation.l

Answer (score 3):

It is not too hard to show that if $\eta$ is continuous then $\|F\| = \|\eta\|_1$ using a sequence of approximations to $\operatorname{sgn} \eta$ (or the complex equivalent).

The continuous functions are dense in $L^1[0,1]$, so there is a sequence of continuous 
functions $h_n$ such that $\|h-h_n\|_1 \to 0$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose a continuous $h_n$ such that $\|h-h_n\|_1 < \epsilon$ and so $\|h_n\|_1 > \|h\|_1 -\epsilon$. Now choose $g$ with $\|g\|_\infty = 1$ such that $| \int h_n g |  \ge \|h\|_1-\epsilon$.

We have $||\int h g| - |\int h_n g|| \le |\int h g - \int h_n g| \le \|g\|_\infty \|h-h_n\|_1 < \epsilon $.

Combining, $|\int hg| \ge |\int h_n g|-\epsilon \ge  \|h\|_1 - 2 \epsilon$ and so
$\sup_{\|g\|_\infty \le 1} |\int hg| = \|h\|_1$.

Comment: but $h$ is integrable not continuous

Comment: @Secretly: I understand, what is your point?

Comment: in your first line you are saying that "It is not too hard to show that if $h$ is continuous then ...." how did you overcome this proof?

Comment: @Secretly: That is a statement, if $\eta$ is continuous then the norm of the operator $F(g) = \int \eta g$ is $\|\eta\|_1$. So, if $h_n$ is continuous, the operator $g \mapsto \int h_n g$ has norm $\|h_n\|_1$. Hence in the above, we have $\|h_n||_1 > \|h\|_1 - \epsilon$, so we can find a unit norm $g$ such that $\int g h_n > \|h\|_1 - \epsilon$.

Comment: do you have a proof for this statement?